# apache website to NGINX website

Tags: php, apache, nginx

So recently my company started running websites on nginx instead of apache. Our application makes use of codeigniter.

So after uploading the source code a lot of url's werent working and i managed to get everything to work for codeigniter.

But we have a part of the website that doesnt work and also isnt codeigniter its a piece of code by itself /simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/surfconext-uvt. It used to create simplesaml requests and login.

The config file right now is:

```
server
{
    listen X.X.X.X:443 ssl http2;
    server_name X;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/domains/X.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/domains/X.nl.bytes bytes;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/domains/X.nl.error.log;
    root /home/u10024/domains/X.nl/private_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

     location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    location /simplesaml {
        rewrite ^/simplesaml/(.*) /simplesamlphp/www/$1 break;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$
        {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include /etc/nginx/nginx_limits.conf;
            if (-f $request_filename)
            {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/usr/local/php71/sockets/u10024.sock;
            }
        }

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/u10024/domains/X.nl.cert.combined;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/u10024/domains/X.nl.key;

    include /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/u10024/nginx_php.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/webapps.ssl.conf;
}
```

I know close to nothing about nginx and am struggling to understand what i need to do here... Some help would be highly appreciated.